# How to navigate to a specific route if user logged in for the first time?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I've an Angular 2+, Node.js, Express.js app with registration/login authentication features.

I want to navigate the user to a specific route if the user is logging in for the first time and then the subsequent login's default navigate to the home route?

Comment: Seems like a pretty standard practice;  What part of the code you wrote for this task isn't working?

Comment: Just not sure how to make it work - I haven't started with this as want to get an idea

Comment: see this http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/09/29/angular-2-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

have a variable related to your user profile, if this variable is false then redirect to your specific component and update the variable in the database to true, so the second time that the users enter will go to the normal route

**UPDATED**

you need to create a action that set the variable to true in the backend, this action will be executed on the ngOnInit method of your "temporally component" (the one that you going to show only one)

Other solution can be creating a local storage variable that save this flag. the mechanism to saved is going to be the explained before

Comment: so how to set that variable to true if the user logins?